# Errors in showing this function is well-defined.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and let $Y$ be a dense linear subspace of $X$. Define $\phi:X^*\rightarrow Y^*$ by $\phi(f)=f|_Y$. Then I want to show $\phi$ is well-defined. And here is my attempt:

For all $f\in X^*$, $f|_Y$ is a continuous linear functional on $Y$; that is, $f|_Y\in Y^*$. If $f_1=f_2\in X^*$, then $\phi(f_1)=f_1|_Y=f_2|_Y=\phi(f_2)$. Hence, $\phi:X^*\rightarrow Y^*$ is well -defined.

But my professor said my proof was wrong in logic. It seems ok to me. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should more explicitly show that $f|_Y$ is bounded:

$$\|f|_Y\|_{Y^*} = \sup_{y \in Y, \|y\| = 1} |f|_Y(y)| = \sup_{y \in Y, \|y\| = 1} |f(y)| \le \sup_{y \in X, \|y\| = 1} |f(y)| = \|f\|_{X^*}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer but he told me to fix the logic here. But I couldn't find any logic mistakes.

Comment: @AnswerLee Well, $f_1 = f_2 \implies f_1|_Y = f_2|_Y$ is a bit unnecessary as it is clear.

Comment: But I don't think it is a logic error. May be just redundant.

Comment: @AnswerLee Yes, that's what I meant.